# How to configure AAMs in SP 2010 to work with ISA 2006 and Kerberos authentication?

Tags: kerberos, sharepoint-2010, isa-server

We are attempting to set up SharePoint Foundation to use Kerberos constrained delegation with ISA Server 2006. My current issue is that the alternate access mappings are not working properly.

Issues:

1. None of the drop down menus and other dialogs are working. Just say "loading" but dsiplay nothing.
2. View source shows that the wrong URL is being used - kdelegated rather than `sp10b.domain.com`
3. Open in Windows Explorer function opens `\\kdelegated.localdom.net\library` and not via the correct https connection.
4. Email a link function used the kdelegated URL as well.

I am using this article as my guide to publishing the site.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261814(office.12).aspx

Public Name  : `sp10b.domain.com`
Internal Name: `kdelegated.localdom.net`

I am not using link translation on the ISA server as this should be taken care of via the AAM. Here is a shot of the AAM page[image]

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a typo in the AAM. Notice that on the third line of the graphic the protocol should be http and not https under Internal URL. Error correction in my brain seems to have not allowed me to see this until I came in the next morning. I will leave this question up in case some other fool makes the same mistake.